# SQL CLR Programmability - Synchronization

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, clr

I'm new to SQL CLR programmability. I have a CLR stored procedure that writes to a local file. But when I have multiple connections calling the same stored procedure, how do I synchronize access to the local file? Any inbuilt features? Or any other input is welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Safe CLR assemblies inside SQL are not allowed to share state and hence cannot synchronize. For good reason, by blocking in synchronization you steal a worker from the SQL Server thread pool. Workers are in high demand, can't afford to loose them waiting for user synch. Unsafe assemblies can do anything using ordinary .Net Framework synchronization objects (Monitor, lock statements, ReaderWriter lock etc etc), but that's why they called 'unsafe': you may end up freezing the SQL Server instance.

Do your file access and synchronization from an external process.

Comment: Hi I have an unsafe assembly only.. But still each connection executes the SP in its own context it seems. So still lock statements do not work..Any idea on how to share state..

Comment: Suppose I'm locking a dictionary object.  Can I switch to using ConcurrentDictionary and remove the locks?

Comment: @Triynko: don't ask questions in comments, post new questions.

Comment: I guess I was looking for clarification.  The problem is that ConcurrentDictionary exists in a "safe" CLR assembly that is supported by SQL Server (mscorlib).  After researching the topic, it appears that the supported assemblies are not entirely safe, since certain framework classes and methods have attributes whose use is restricted in safe assemblies.  So although ConcurrentDictionary exists in an assembly that is generally considered safe, it uses the HostProtectionAttribute's Synchronization and ExternalThreading options, both of which are restricted, and will throw a runtime exception.